# TL074 TSSOP (tl074cpwr) Running Hot ? Normal ? About 40 celcius on the infrared thermometer

Tags: operational-amplifier

Hello i'm wondering if it's normal (at what temp i should be concerned about the heat) and safe for long term use to run TL074 TSSOP (tl074cpwr) at about 40 celcius, that's what my infrared thermometer says, it's accurate i tested it with other stuff. When i touch it, it feels pretty hot compared to all the other circuit i used this chip on, it's not burning hot to the point i can't leave my finger on it but it's pretty hot. This is a very simple circuit used from many including respectable designers out there, i see this circuit all the time when buffered signals are needed. I did not notice heat when touching soic 074 but with this tssop version it's kinda hot to the touch after only 1-2 minute and it gets cold as soon as i remove the power. I found some people saying it's normal, and others saying a chip should not run hot... I'm kinda confused because everyone seems to use about the same circuit like this but i don't see any one talking about the chip getting hot. I checked the connections and soldering 10 times, also tried many different chips from different supliers, ST and TI ... Some of them directly from TI Store... They behave all the same.
Thank you!

EDIT: I just made the same circuit on breadboard with tssop to dip adapter and it's the same temperature. I did that to see if the pcb had an issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How much current is the chip driving?

Comment: ... but that's not particularly hot.

Comment: Last time i checked it was -12v: 25mA and +12v: 20mA... That's for 2 of theses combined (2 x tl074cpwr) plus the 2 leds, everything in the circuit was this measurement. Is there anything coming to your mind that could cause what i describe?

Comment: I measured current drawn by the +12v side on one chip power pin 4, it's between 7 and 15mA. About 7ma seems to be used by the led. When the led is off it's just 7mA, then 15 when led is on.

Comment: 0.09mA at the input socket.

Comment: The IC should draw around 6 to 8 mA. At 24V, that's around 170mW which means the part should be slightly warm. 40°C (just slightly above body temp) is probably within reason. 90uA on the input sounds fishy, should be almost zero for a JFET input. Check for oscillation with an oscilloscope.

Comment: There's no oscillation, maybe the cheap breadboard was giving the 90uA at the input

Comment: where you see the max mA draw for this chip in the datasheet?

Comment: This all looks normal on the face it  .If you want to do things properly then measure your ambient temp and write down delta T .Get the thermal resistance of the chip in K per watt . Calc your power dissipation in watts from your supply volts and amps .Now calc Junction temp to decide if it is OK.